# Is there an app for Mac to check app network activity?

Tags: network

I want to know what and where one of my apps trying to download from.

Comment: I don't know if these do exactly what you want. I haven't used any of them super extensively, but as a quick nudge to a direction, I'd maybe look into these: [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html), [Hands Off!](https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/handsoff/), [Radio Silence](https://radiosilenceapp.com/).

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a hardware/software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Comment: Try Network Utility or  `netstat` in the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an app called Wireshark to monitor internet traffic. It by default shows all network traffic but you can narrow it to your system only using a filter.